# Rendering lit component with incremental async updates

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, lit

I have to render a list of items using lit components. Each list item composed of the `name`, which is know at load time, and the `value` which is fetched asynchronously.

**Some Context:**

- There needs to be a generic component `simple-list` which renders any pairs of `name` and `value`
- There is also a `foo-list` component which contains the configuration for a specific set of pairs and passes the data to the `simple-list` component
- The time to fetch each `value` can vary and their responses come in at different times
- When the `foo-list` component is first loaded, it should show every `name` with the `value` set to `"Loading..."`
- As the response for each `value` arrives, the relevant text in the list should be updated to show the retrieved value.

I am having trouble getting the component to re-render for each update. My code for the `simple-list` and `foo-list` components is below.

- The `simple-list` component takes a data object and re-renders its list every time a new object is passed.
- The `foo-list` component initially passes `simple-list` all the names with temporary values, gets the values for each name and passes an updated data object every time a value comes in.
- I'm guessing that it's not possible to call `this.requestUpdate` from within an async anonymous method, but I don't see a better way to structure this
- If there's a better to pass data or instructions into the `simple-list` component that would be great

How can I have `getDataAndUpdate` show the initial value and also the updated values as the promises resolve?

```
// Simple-List.ts

import { html, LitElement } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";

export type SimpleListItem = {  name: string, value: string };

@customElement("simple-list")
export class SimpleList extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Array, attribute: false })
  items: SimpleListItem[] = [];
  update(changedProperties: Map<string, unknown>) {
    super.update(changedProperties);
    if (changedProperties.has("items")) {
      this.requestUpdate();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return html`<ul>${this.items.map((item) => html`<li>${item.name}: ${item.value}</li>`)}</ul>`;
  }
}
```

```
// Foo-List.ts

import { html, LitElement } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";

import "./Simple-List";
import { SimpleListItem } from "./Simple-List";

async function getValue(name: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Value for ${name}`);
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}

@customElement("foo-list")
export class MyFoo extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Array })
  names: string[] = [];

  @property({ type: Array, attribute: false })
  data: SimpleListItem[] = [];

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.getDataAndUpdate();
  }

  update(changedProperties: Map<string, unknown>) {
    super.update(changedProperties);
    if (changedProperties.has("names")) {
      this.getDataAndUpdate();
    }
  }

  async getDataAndUpdate() {
    this.data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
      const value = "loading...";
      const name = this.names[i];
      (async () => {
        this.data[i] = { name , value: await getValue(name) };
        this.requestUpdate();
      })();
      this.data.push({ name, value });
    }
    this.requestUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    return html` <simple-list .items=${this.data}></simple-list> `;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

The easier thing to do would be to allow `<simple-list>` to accept the promise as a value and use the [`until()` directive](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#until).

```
// Simple-List.ts

import { html, LitElement } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";
import { until } from "lit/directives/until.js";

export type SimpleListItem = { name: string, value: Promise<string> };

@customElement("simple-list")
export class SimpleList extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Array, attribute: false })
  items: SimpleListItem[] = [];

  // The update() override in original code is unnecessary

  render() {
    return html`<ul>${this.items.map((item) => html`<li>${item.name}: ${until(item.value, "Loading...")}</li>`)}</ul>`;
  }
}
```

```
// Foo-List.ts

import { html, LitElement } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";

import "./Simple-List";
import { SimpleListItem } from "./Simple-List";

async function getValue(name: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Value for ${name}`);
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}

@customElement("foo-list")
export class MyFoo extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Array })
  names: string[] = [];

  render() {
    const items = this.names.map((name) => ({ name, value: getValue(name)}));
    return html`<simple-list .items=${items}></simple-list>`;
  }
}
```

Here's a working example: https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=803e84382d62a192ec21120ed2bfb0d7

### Solution 2

If `<simple-list>` needs to stick to only receiving primitive data, then `<foo-list>` needs to be responsible for updating the props given to it.
We can use [`willUpdate()` lifecycle](https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#willupdate) to synchronously set the state with the placeholder value. Each value promise resolution will update the state following immutable pattern so change detection triggers updates for both `<foo-list>` and `<simple-list>` that receives it.

```
// Simple-List.ts

import { html, LitElement } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";

export type SimpleListItem = { name: string, value: string };

@customElement("simple-list")
export class SimpleList extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Array, attribute: false })
  items: SimpleListItem[] = [];

  render() {
    return html`<ul>${this.items.map((item) => html`<li>${item.name}: ${item.value}</li>`)}</ul>`;
  }
}
```

```
// Foo-List.ts

import { html, LitElement, PropertyValues } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";

import "./Simple-List";
import { SimpleListItem } from "./Simple-List";

async function getValue(name: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Value for ${name}`);
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}

@customElement("foo-list")
export class MyFoo extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Array })
  names: string[] = [];

  @state()
  _data: SimpleListItem[] = [];
  
  willUpdate(changedProperties: PropertyValues<this>) {
    if (changedProperties.has('names')) {
      this._data = this.names.map((name) => {
        getValue(name).then((value) => {
          // Create a new array reference to trigger update after data is available
          this._data = this._data.map((item) => {
            if (item.name === name) {
              return {
                name: item.name,
                value,
              }
            }
            return item;
          });
        });
        return {
          name,
          value: 'Loading...',
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return html`<simple-list .items=${this._data}></simple-list>`;
  }
}
```

Here it is in action: https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=18e5ef43c646b94c130f3aa0410c68e9

#### Solution 3

Here's another way to keep a cache of results in the component and use `this.requestUpdate()` on promise resolution instead.

```
// Foo-List.ts

import { html, LitElement, PropertyValues } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";

import "./simple-list.js";
import { SimpleListItem } from "./simple-list.js";

async function getValue(name: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Value for ${name}`);
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}

@customElement("foo-list")
export class MyFoo extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Array })
  names: string[] = [];
  
  private _values = new Map<string, string>();
  private _getValue(name: string): string {
    const value = this._values.get(name);
    if (value === undefined) {
      getValue(name).then(val => {
        this._values.set(name, val);
        this.requestUpdate();
      });
    }
    return value ?? 'Loading...'
  }

  render() {
    const items = this.names.map((name) => ({
      name,
      value: this._getValue(name)
    }))
    return html`<simple-list .items=${items}></simple-list>`;
  }
}
```

In action: https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=374c95aa0d0ef80e3745beeafee2bec4